# Error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I try to create comments for post, it gives me this error

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #6):
```

This is my comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This is my comment create table migration

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  drop_table :comments
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I hope you will help me.

Comment: do you have anything like this in your controller? `params.require(:comment).permit(. . . )`

Comment: You have to permit your params as well as  change like @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])

Comment: No, i don't have this params.require in my comment controller

Comment: you have to permit your params in your controller. see this: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `comments_controller` should look somewhat like this:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :user_id, :content)
end
```

And, I highly recommend you to read the [Rails Official documentation for Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: One more question how i can delete comment?

Comment: You can do it in a number of ways, e.g. `Comment.find(15).destroy` or ``Comment.find(15).delete` Or, if you have a paritucular comment: `@comment = Commen.where(...).first` you can just do: `@comment.delete`

Comment: Like this: `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])` and 
    `@comment.destroy`

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/rakibulislam/0652195fd87eac1a751c#file-comments_controller-rb-L42-L50. This is taken from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/getting_started.html

Comment: undefined method `set_comment' for #<CommentsController:0x007f71b074efe0>

Comment: case filter
        when Symbol
          lambda { |target, _, &blk| target.send filter, &blk }
        when String
          l = eval "lambda { |value| #{filter} }"
          lambda { |target, value| target.instance_exec(value, &l) }

Comment: error in this line lambda { |target, _, &blk| target.send filter, &blk }

Comment: You have `before_action :set_comment` on the top of your controller, but did you really `set_comment` method? Seems like you did not. That'w why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't register your strong parameter of comments.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :user_id, :content)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have updated my code. You have to register you strong parameters and change `create(comment_params)` into `new(comment_params)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the params set in the file, it looks like you did not post the whole thing but if not, try something like this.

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
```

Then down at the bottom of the file make a private method

```
private   
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id,:user_id,:content)
  end
```